# Install ImageMagick with liquid-rescale support

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, imagemagick

I have installed ImageMagick 6.5.8 from source on Ubuntu 8.10 followed by the instructions listed [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php#unix)

```
> tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz
> cd ImageMagick-6.5.8
> ./configure
> make
> sudo make install
```

Installation was successful but when I try to use 'liquid-rescale' operator it showed:

```
> convert source.png -liquid-rescale 500x500 output.png
convert: delegate library support not built-in `source.png' (LQR) @ resize.c/LiquidRescaleImage/1550.
```

Looks like it was compiled without liquid-rescale support.

I wonder how to turn on liquid-rescale when installing ImageMagick from source.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you have the liblqr headers installed when you compiled imagemagick?

If you're on Debian/Ubuntu, you need to install the `liblqr-1-0-dev` package.

If you are on Ubuntu, you can also search PPAs. [This PPA](https://launchpad.net/~cristiklein/+archive/ppa?field.series_filter=karmic) has imagemagick for karmic in 6.5.5.3 so and is built against liblqr, so it should work.

**Edit:** I see you're on Ubuntu Intrepid (8.10), so this PPA won't do. So, to make it as clean as possible without making it too complicated, this is what you can do:

```
  # Create a copy of your sources.list to get the dependencies
  $ cp /etc/apt/sources.list $HOME/imagemagick.list
  # Add the PPA anyway, with deb-src to grab the source
  $ cat <<EOF | tee -a $HOME/imagemagick.list
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/cristiklein/ppa/ubuntu karmic main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/cristiklein/ppa/ubuntu karmic main
EOF
  # install apt-build
  $ sudo apt-get install apt-build
  # For some reason I had to install libgtk2.0-dev (on Karmic at least)
  $ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-dev
  # Build and install imagemagick
  $ sudo apt-build --sources-list $HOME/imagemagick.list install imagemagick
```

That said, Intrepid is getting quite old, and is not even an LTS version, so I'd recommend upgrading.